# Spring Boot: How to disable startup log message "Starting Application on mbp with PID 99446"

Tags: logging, spring-boot

There are some log messages on the application startup:

```
2016-11-01 10:13:49.468  INFO 99446 --- [  restartedMain] s7.Application                           : Starting Application on mbp with PID 99446 (/Users/serge/projects/scratches/s7/build/classes/main started by serge in /Users/serge/projects/scratches/s7)
2016-11-01 10:13:49.469  INFO 99446 --- [  restartedMain] s7.Application                           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-11-01 10:13:52.642  INFO 99446 --- [  restartedMain] s7.Application                           : Started Application in 3.573 seconds (JVM running for 3.973)
```

How to disable them? I want to be able to log in my application, but I don't need these log messages.

My application.properties have these settings:

```
spring.main.banner-mode=off
logging.level.org.springframework=WARN
logging.level.org.apache=WARN
logging.level.org.mongodb=WARN
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can disable those three log messages by configuring your `SpringApplication` not to log startup info:

```
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(YourApplication.class)
               .logStartupInfo(false)
               .run(args);
```

Alternatively, if you want to stick with your log levels-based approach, they are logged using the logger for you application's main class. Judging by the output above, it's called `s7.Application` so you can also disable the messages by adding the following to `application.properties`:

```
logging.level.s7.Application=WARN
```

Comment: Setting spring.main.log-startup-info: false also works.

Answer (score 14):

You can disable the messages by adding the following to application.properties:

```
spring.main.log-startup-info=OFF
```