# Print only application logs

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, logging

I want to print my logs of Spring Boot application, but I want to print my application logs in INFO. It is writing everything from server startup to stop.

I want to write logs in INFO, that I wrote into my application.

How to do it in Spring Boot?

Comment: check this; https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-custom-log-levels

Answer (score 0):

Disable startup log messages by envoking `.logStartupInfo(false)` in your Application builder.

It should look like:

```
new SpringApplicationBuilder(ServiceConfiguration.class)
.logStartupInfo(false)
.run(args);
```

Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40359108/spring-boot-how-to-disable-startup-log-message-starting-application-on-mbp-wit) for more clarity.

**OR**

Add logback.xml inside src/main/resources and the contents should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %magenta([%thread]) %highlight(%-5level) %logger{36}.%M - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="off">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

For more information please take a look at this [link](https://dzone.com/articles/configuring-logback-with-spring-boot)

Comment: where to write this??

Comment: In the class which has @SpringBootApplication and has your main method

Comment: please share your application.properties file

Comment: spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.database=oauthserver
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost/oauthserver
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
server.servlet.context-path=/otp
logging.path=/mnt/vol1/anchor/logs
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=false
something like this

Comment: Add ' logging.level.org.springframework.web: FATAL ' in application.properties file.
If this doesnt work either I would like to see your logs

Comment: Addition to that do you have any logging configuration file (ex. log4j.xml) in your code base

Comment: Edited the answer and added one more approach to stop logging using configuring logback with spring.